# Control file upload scenario execution in jmeter

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I have file upload scenario in jmeter,my requirement is suppose 5th request is file upload. So few users should upload single file and few users should upload multiple files . Suppose in iteration 1, single file is uploaded now in next iteration multiple files need to be uploaded using same 5th request. I don't want to create two thread group.

Any suggestions please.

Tried getting iteration num in multiple of 2, using output in if controller but it's not working